# C# - A request to send data was disallowed because the socket is not connected

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ip, chat

I am coding a chat application as an intro for me to sockets. I was trying to get the clients and servers IP address and save it to a `richtextbox`. I put it into a thread and whenever there is a connection pending, it will accept and get the IP address, but it fails out in debug mode. Please advice. Thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AcceptTcpClient()` returns the `TcpClient` for the incoming connection.
Try this code:

```
var client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
var remoteEndPoint = _currentClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint;
```